# How can I calculate the correlation in these 9 androgen-dependent areas?

Tags: correlation

I know that the correlation bethween CAG Repeats and hair growth in 13 studied areas is r=-0.538. What I also know is that the correlation of CAG Repeats with hair score only holds for 9 of the 13 studied areas. I know that the correlation bethween CAG Repeats and hair score in the 4 other non-androgen dependent regions is close to zero. How can I with this provided information be able to know/calculate how strong the correlation bethween CAG Repeats and hair score in the 9 androgen dependent areas which makes uo all of the correlation bethween CAG Repeat and hair score is?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain (or link) about the context. And perhaps this is better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @leonbloy explaining the context (and any effort) is far preferable than posting a link, which is seldom appreciated.